# Ordenação por data no MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Eu tenho uma tabela com dois campos: `dh_premium_expires` e `score`.

> dh_premium_expires - a data/hora que a premium do usuário irá expirar.
>
> score - score do usuário dentro do jogo.

No meu site eu tenho uma lista aonde eu listo esses usuários, e atualmente eu estou ordenando da seguinte maneira:

```
ORDER BY dh_premium_expires DESC, score DESC;
```

Eu quero que venha primeiro os usuários premiums e depois os com maiores score. Dessa forma está funcionando, porem tem um problema, os usuários premiuns com mais tempo de premium estão ficando no topo e eu queria que ficasse nessa ordem:

> Usuários premiuns com maior score.
> Usuários premiuns.
> Usuários com maior score.

Para isso eu teria que criar uma variável setando 1 para quem é premium (dh_premium_expires > data de hoje) e 0 para quem não é ou já expirou. Assim ficaria correto eu acho.

Como faço isso no MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não é preciso criar mais um campo, isso só vai "poluir" a sua base de dados.
Veja, pode ser feito da seguinte maneira:

```
SELECT 
    IF(dh_premium_expires<now(),0,1) as premium, dh_premium_expires, score 
FROM 
    tabela 
ORDE BY 
    premium DESC, score DESC
```

A query acima verifica se o registo é premium ou não inserindo no resultado da sua query 0 ou 1. Todos os que possuem "1" (conta premium) aparecem primeiro e depois ordenamos pelo score.

Comment: Funcionou muito bem, obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

você já tentou

```
select 
dh_premium_expires , score, case when (dh_premium_expires > DATA_HORA) then 1 else 0 end as ISPremium
from
  TABELA
```